# How to extend the pyscipopt interface?

Tags: python, optimization, scip

I understand that we need to add the required function to scip.pyx, and also to scip.pxd. But can someone please explain how to compile these new files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make your adjustments and extensions in the code and then install (which includes the compilation step) the updated module as described in [INSTALL.md](https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.md):

```
python -m pip install .
```

Comment: Thank you. So, if I understand correctly, I need to follow the instructions to install from the source. TO do this, I cloned the repository in my home directory, and then ran the command which you suggested. That worked fine, and I was able to test the installation on the examples in the repo. But then when I changed scip.pyx, and ran the above command, the installation was removed from the site-packages directory and I am getting ModuleNotFound error now. Can you please help me with that. Thanks

Comment: The issue seems to be with the -e flag. If I remove it, things work as expected

Comment: Interesting, I'll just remove the -e flag from the installation directions to avoid further confusion. Thanks for the feedback!